# Anyone having an idea how to implement a polyphase filter using c programming

Tags: c, signal-processing

Does anyone knows how to implement a polyphase filter using C programming. Polyphase filter is a combination of filtering plus down sampling. It uses an Fir filter for filtering and then down sample it with the given decimation factor.

I understand with filtering it's the convolution of the input signal with the impulse response, so you just have to call the convolution function.

In simple terms the code would be like this.

```
for ( i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++ ) 
{ 
    y[i] = 0; // set to zero before sum 
    for ( j = 0; j < kernelCount; j++ ) 
    { 
        y[i] += x[i - j] * h[j]; // convolve: multiply and accumulate 
    } 
}
```

The question I have is how should I convert this basic algorithm to a polyphase filter, because it has one more step as down sampling. I do not understanding what should I do 1st, Filtering and then down sampling? or is there a way to combine both and do it?

Comment: `while (<data_available>) output = downsample(fir(input), decimation_factor);`

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question per say, but it is lacking per the [FAQ] and needs some work. Do you know how to create a normal filter? And how to do down sampling? Have you tried to create a polyphase filter and not been successful or are you stuck on coming up with an algorithm? Where specifically are you stuck right now, where have your efforts and research taken you?

Comment: Yeah i know how to do filtering. Its the convolution of the input signal with the impulse response, so you just have to call the convolution function. I mean the basic idea of convolution. In simple terms the code would be like this.for ( i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++ )
{
    y[i] = 0;                       // set to zero before sum
    for ( j = 0; j < kernelCount; j++ )
    {
        y[i] += x[i - j] * h[j];    // convolve: multiply and accumulate
    }
}

Comment: The real problem is how to implement a polyphase filter because it has one more step as down sampling. I am not understanding what should I do 1st I do Filtering and then down sampling? or is there a way to combine both and do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You have code to calculate each point. For any point `i`, that code uses data in `x[i-j]` and `h[j]` (looping over values of `j`), and it writes the result to `y[i]`.

For downsampling, you do not want all the points `y[i]`; you only want some of them. So write code that, given an `i`, uses data in the same `x[i-j]` and `h[j]` to calculate the output value. But, instead of doing that for every value of `i`, do it only for multiples of the decimation factor (say it is named `d`), and write the result to `y[i/d]` instead of `y[i]`.